# How to assign the shortest-distance to all agents in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo, shortest-path, a-star, multi-agent

## How to assign the shortest-distance to all agents

- Current status: My codes only finds the shortest-path for 1 person but cannot when there are more than 1 person.
- **Question: How can I assign the shortest-path for each person?**

### Background

I manipulated the traffic grid model inside the NetLogo model library to create a shortest-path algorithm for pedestrians (somewhat close to A*). The interface below shows that an agent is standing on its origin which is coloured in pale yellow, and has the same colour as a destination. It also works fine for 3 people.

- 1 person
  [image: 1 person]
- 3 people
  [image: 3 people]

### Setup

Here is a code chunck that I wrote as a setup. It doesn't seem to have any problem in this section.

```
globals
[
  grid-x-inc               ;; the amount of patches in between two roads in the x direction
  grid-y-inc               ;; the amount of patches in between two roads in the y direction
  intersections ;; agentset containing the patches that are intersections
  roads         ;; agentset containing the patches that are roads
  population
]

breed[people person]

patches-own
[

  father
  navigated?
  active?
  Heuristic
  step
  total-cost
  is-intersection?
  start
  finish
]

people-own
[
  origin
  destination
  h-distance ;; short for heuristic distance. Euclidean distance to goal
  path
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-globals
  setup-patches
  setup-people
  setup-destination
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-globals
  set grid-x-inc world-width / grid-size-x
  set grid-y-inc world-height / grid-size-y

  ask patches
  [
    set father nobody
    set navigated? false
    set active? false
    set total-cost 0
  ]
end


to setup-patches
  ;; initialize the patch-owned variables and color the patches to a base-color
  ask patches [ set pcolor brown + 3 ]

  ;; initialize the global variables that hold patch agentsets
  set roads patches with
    [(floor((pxcor + max-pxcor - floor(grid-x-inc - 1)) mod grid-x-inc) = 0) or
    (floor((pycor + max-pycor) mod grid-y-inc) = 0)]
  set intersections roads with
    [(floor((pxcor + max-pxcor - floor(grid-x-inc - 1)) mod grid-x-inc) = 0) and
    (floor((pycor + max-pycor) mod grid-y-inc) = 0)]
  ask roads [ set pcolor white ]

  ask intersections [ set is-intersection? true
    ask neighbors [ set is-intersection? true ]]

end


to setup-people
    create-people no-of-people
  [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1
    set color black
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != brown + 3]
    set origin patch-here
    set destination one-of patches with [pcolor != brown + 3 and is-intersection? != true]
    set h-distance distance destination
  ]
  set population []  ;; create list of individuals
  let sort-turtles sort people set population sort-turtles
end


to setup-destination
foreach population [ individual ->
  ask individual [
   let roads_ roads with [pcolor = white]
   ask roads_ [
     set navigated? false
     set active? false
     set Heuristic 0
     set step 0
     set total-cost 0
     set start false
     set finish false
   ]]
    let current [origin] of individual
    let target [destination] of individual

ask individual [
    if target != nobody [
      ask current [
        set pcolor (10 + random 130)
        set step 0
        set start true
        set finish false
        set navigated? false
      ]
      ask target [
        set pcolor [pcolor] of current
        set navigated? true
        set start false
        set finish true
      ]]
  ]]
end
```

### Problem 1: Set all paths

`set-path` traces all the steps from the origin patch to everywhere inside the virtual world. The code will colour the road to yellow and add a label on the path. This procedure will repeat 50 times to find all the possible steps.

**The problem occurs from this section where this code only works for one agent not for the entire agents.**

```
to set-path

repeat 50 [
  ask patches with [pcolor = white and pcolor != yellow] [
      if any? neighbors4 with [ start = true ] or
       any? neighbors4 with [ pcolor = yellow ]
    [ set pcolor yellow
      let laststep [step] of one-of neighbors4 with [pcolor = yellow or
                                                            start = true]
        ifelse [plabel] of patches != nobody [
          set step laststep + 1
          set plabel step
          set father step
          set total-cost father + heuristic
          set plabel-color red][set plabel ""]
  ]]]

  let allroads [self] of patches with [pcolor != brown]
  let final_location one-of patches with [finish = true]

  foreach allroads [ road_patch ->
    ask road_patch [set Heuristic distance final_location]
    ]
end
```

### Problem 2: Set shortest path

This procedure finds the shortest path by finding the patches and adding them to a list named `path`. Because the previous procedure only worked for one agent this procedure will also assign the patches to one agent, which is not what I want.

```
to shortest-path
  ask patches with [start = true] [
    let maxsteps 0
    ask patches with [navigated? = true]
  [ let check-steps min-one-of neighbors4 with
        [pcolor != brown + 3 and pcolor != white][step]
    set maxsteps [step] of check-steps
  ]

  let num (range maxsteps 0 -1)
  let paths []

  foreach num [ navigation ->
  ask patches with [navigated? = true] [
    let nav-patch min-one-of neighbors4 with
        [step = navigation and pcolor != brown + 3][step]
    if nav-patch != nobody [ask nav-patch [set navigated? true set paths fput self paths]]
    ]]
  ask people [set path paths]

    ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = yellow][set pcolor white set plabel ""]
end
```

### Summary: What I want the model to look like

- **How can I assign the shortest-path for each person if there are more than 2 people inside NetLogo?**
- What I want the model to look like
  [image]
- File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gxhkcnlBniB5M4aSYmt65PE6LBekgVp6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you describe whý it only works for 1 agent? what is happening now when you try to run it with 5 agents?